# Transform JSON with /UI2/CL_JSON deserialize then serialize

Tags: json, serialization, abap

I need to transform JSON.

I am getting output as `"0000010006  GLAESS"`, but I need `{"customer_id":"0000010006","customer":"GLAESS"}`

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_field,
         customer_id  TYPE string,
         address      TYPE string,
         created_time TYPE string,
         customer     TYPE string,
         date_created TYPE string,
       END OF ty_field,
       BEGIN OF ty_record,
         id          TYPE string,
         createdtime TYPE string,
         fields      TYPE ty_field,
       END OF ty_record,
       BEGIN OF ty_response,
         records TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_record WITH EMPTY KEY,
       END OF ty_response.
DATA:ls_response TYPE ty_response.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA(resp) = `{"records":[{"id":"rec5Qk24OQpKDyykq","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010001","address":"Chennai","time_created":"06:00:14","customer":"IDADMIN","date_created":"16.04.2004"}},{"id":"rec7bSe8` &&
  `Zb18z6b5a","createdTime":"2022-08-08T13:07:16.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010007","address":"Kakinada","time_created":"04:01:18","customer":"Ramya","date_created":"15.04.2000"}},{"id":"recD9Hh4YLgNXOhUE","createdTime":"2022-08-08T11:48:06.00` &&
  `0Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010002","address":"Bangalore","time_created":"04:03:35","customer":"MAASSBERG","date_created":"20.04.2004"}},{"id":"recK7Tfw4PFAedDiB","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010005","a` &&
  `ddress":"Kakinada","time_created":"12:55","customer":"Lakshmi","date_created":"13-10-2022"}},{"id":"recKOq0DhEtAma7BV","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010006","address":"Hyderabad","time_created":"18:42:28","cu` &&
  `stomer":"GLAESS","date_created":"21.04.2004"}},{"id":"recS8pg10dFBGj8o7","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010003","address":"Gurugram","time_created":"04:10:02","customer":"MAASSBERG","date_created":"20.04.2004"` &&
  `}},{"id":"recf4QbOmKMrBeLQZ","createdTime":"2022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010004","address":"Bangalore","time_created":"06:00:12","customer":"IDADMIN","date_created":"21.04.2004"}},{"id":"recs7oHEqfkN87tWm","createdTime":"2` &&
  `022-08-03T10:14:43.000Z","fields":{"customer_id":"0000010000","address":"Hyderabad","time_created":"04:01:18","customer":"MAASSBERG","date_created":"15.04.2004"}}]}`.

  /ui2/cl_json=>deserialize(
      EXPORTING
          json = resp
          pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-user
      CHANGING
          data = ls_response ).

  DATA(ls_first_entry) = ls_response-records[ 5 ].

  DATA(opt) = ls_first_entry-fields-customer_id && ` ` && ls_first_entry-fields-customer .

  DATA(output) = /ui2/cl_json=>serialize(
                  data = opt
                  compress = abap_true
                  pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case ).
```

Comment: I spent 10 minutes to review and edit your question. Next time, please post a syntax-error free [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serialize to a JSON object, you must use the corresponding ABAP structure. Currently you are serializing an abap string to json, that's why you get a simple json string.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_serialize,
         customer_id  TYPE string,
         customer     TYPE string,
       END OF ty_serialize.

" Note: we build a structure, and not a string
DATA(ls_serialize) = VALUE ty_serialize( customer_id = ls_first_entry-fields-customer_id customer = ls_first_entry-fields-customer ).
DATA(lv_json1) = /ui2/cl_json=>serialize( data        = ls_serialize
                                          compress    = abap_true
                                          pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-low_case ).

" Result: {"customer_id":"0000010006","customer":"GLAESS"}
```

Comment: now i need to check this obatined json is valid or not

'''DATA : lv_string TYPE string 
lv_string = lv_json1. 
DATA(lo_reader) = cl_sxml_string_reader=>create( cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to( lv_json ) ).
TRY.
    lo_reader->next_node( ).
    lo_reader->skip_node( ).
    cl_demo_output=>display( 'JSON is valid' ).
  CATCH cx_sxml_parse_error INTO DATA(lx_parse_error).
    cl_demo_output=>display( lx_parse_error->get_text( ) ).
ENDTRY.'''
here i am getting an error code page is not permitted

Comment: What's `lv_json`? Did you mean `lv_json1` or `lv_string`? You could also use [this](https://help.sap.com/docs/BTP/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/492ccdb87b224a35a8ed20e53325dfce.html) and catch the exception it throws on deserialization.

Comment: i am done with validation of api
how to convert this json into csv format

Comment: @PCSVSRINIVAS Please keep focus on your initial question, if the answer solves your initial question mark it as accepted. Don't ask series of different questions inside one question. Please first [make familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/help) with Stack Overflow.